# DirectX assembly reference on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, directx-9

Running my legacy C# application in Windows 10 on Visual Studio 2013 is proving to be a nightmare. The application has an assembly reference to DirectX. Previously, you could just download DirectX SDK and that was 500 MB. Now, you need to download the entire Windows SDK, which is a whopping 4 GB - as they have bundled DirectX together with the Windows SDK. I am lost - the wifi is poor and its taking ages. Any other ideas what i could do? Is DirectX SDK for Windows 10 available separately?

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies. They are *not* in the Windows 10 SDK. They are only deployed by the legacy DirectX SDK and the legacy DirectX Setup package.

See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) and [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-net/).

The legacy DirectX Setup and DirectX SDK will not install the Managed DX 1.1 assemblies unless the system has a .NET 2.0 compatible Runtime (3.5 or 3.0 works as well) installed. It is not supported by .NET 4.0 or later which is what is included with Windows 10 OS.

See [DXSETUP](https://walbourn.github.io/dxsetup-update/) and [Not So Direct Setup](https://walbourn.github.io/not-so-direct-setup/).

Once they are installed, you'll also run into the problem that they don't work with .NET 4.0 which is what VS 2013 is expecting you to use. There are apparently some hacks out there you can try, but MDX was designed for .NET 1.1 originally.

> You should move to something more modern like [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [SlimDX](https://code.google.com/archive/p/slimdx/). *SlimDX* was intended as a replacement for the Managed DX 1.1 assemblies so it's probably the easiest to move to, but the project itself is no longer active.